# Can you store multiple data types in system.array

Tags: c#, .net, covariance

Can you store multiple data types in `System.Array`? All the hits from Google shows I cannot do this, unless the array is object.

Comment: Well, you could define `dynamic[]` and use that just fine.

Comment: Do all of the types that you want to store have a common interface they implement, or a common base class (that's more specific than `object`)?  If not, could you create an interface and have them all implement it?

Comment: @Servy the purpose of this question is to "improve the world". I found this interview question, but all the answers were wrong.

Comment: @lukas Well, you haven't actually linked to any other resources, so we can't really say whether they're right or wrong.  Personally my guess is that they're not *all* wrong, even if some are.  My guess is you're just not properly interpreting them.

Comment: @Servy top 3 form google when you type the title http://www.allinterview.com/showanswers/4681.html Answer: No Another one partially true http://forums.sureshkumar.net/vb-asp-net-interview-technical-questions/16584-c-can-you-store-multiple-data-types-system-array.html Similar: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/interview/exam1663-can-you-store-multiple-data-types-in-systemarray.aspx etc.

Answer (score 11):

You never use `System.Array` directly.

If you want to store different types, use `System.Collections.ArrayList` or  `object[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can store items whose data type is equivalent to, or derived from, the data type of the array. This means that you *can* store multiple data types, provided that they derive from a common base type, or implement a common interface.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN :

> The Array class is the base class for language implementations that
>   support arrays. However, only the system and compilers can derive
>   explicitly from the Array class. Users should employ the array
>   constructs provided by the language.

And Also :

> Type.IsArray and Type.GetElementType might not return the expected
>   results with Array    because if an array is cast to the type Array,
>   the result is an object, not an array. That     is,
>   typeof(System.Array).IsArray returns false, and
>   typeof(System.Array).GetElementType  returns null.

So, in all cases you should avoid creating instances of `System.Array` directly.

Comment: Please format quotes using the quote option, rather than as code, so that you aren't using code highlighting that doesn't make sense in context.

Comment: Ok I was actually wondering how it should be done thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all the answers form the first page of Google are wrong. C# arrays are covariant, because .Net arrays are design to support many languages. Here are examples:

```
class Animal { }
class Cow : Animal { }
class Tiger : Animal { }

 int one = 1;
 double two = 2.0d;
 ValueType[] foo = new ValueType[2];
 foo[0] = one;
 foo[1] = two;

 Animal[] animals = new Animal[2];
 animals[0] = new Cow();
 animals[1] = new Tiger();

 Object[] col = new string[2];
 col[0] = 2; // compiles but throws
```

Comment: You should rarely need to rely on array covariance.  Rather than assigning a `Cow` array to an `Animal` array, when feasible, it's generally better to just create an `Animal` array to begin with if you know you'll need to treat it as such, even if you only assign `Cow` objects to it.